# dpkg: warning: 'tar' not found in PATH or not executable

Tags: software-center

I have installed my programs by "synaptic" previously, but now it shows errors and doesn't install any programs, for example, I want to install `xserver-xorg-dev` but synaptic shows below errors:

```
dpkg: warning: 'tar' not found in PATH or not executable.
dpkg: error: 1 expected program not found in PATH or not executable.
Note: root's PATH should usually contain /usr/local/sbin, /usr/sbin and /sbin.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
A package failed to install.  Trying to recover:
dpkg: warning: 'tar' not found in PATH or not executable.
dpkg: error: 1 expected program not found in PATH or not executable.
Note: root's PATH should usually contain /usr/local/sbin, /usr/sbin and /sbin.
```

Comment: To clarify the PATH problem: type (in a command line) `sudo -i` then type `echo $PATH` and edit your question with the output, then close that session with `exit`.

Comment: Have you ever checked if you have the flipping tar installed? sudo apt-get install tar.

Answer (score 1):

I just solved it. I don't know how sustainable my solution is.

I copied tar from another machine's /bin/tar, then i CHMOD'ed it to 755 on my destination machine's /bin/tar.

now reinstalling tar via apt-get works flawlessly:

```
root@devubuntu:/usr/bin# sudo chmod 755 /bin/tar
root@devubuntu:/usr/bin# sudo apt-get install --reinstall tar
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  xfonts-encodings php-console-table xfonts-utils libmcrypt4 libxfont1 xfonts-base php5-mcrypt
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/218 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 335218 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace tar 1.26-4ubuntu1 (using .../tar_1.26-4ubuntu1_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement tar ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Setting up tar (1.26-4ubuntu1) ...
```

when i use virtualmins "Re-Check Configuration" I now get:

> > All commands needed to create and restore backups are installed.
>
> The selected package management and update systems are installed OK.
>
> .. your system is ready for use by Virtualmin.

please notice, that

> Note: root's PATH should usually contain /usr/local/sbin, /usr/sbin and /sbin.

is just a general information and NOT an actual error message! when I got this message, /usr/local/sbin, /usr/sbin and /sbin **were already** contained in my $PATH variable. so do not let it confuse you.

Comment: This doesn't seem to make too much sense. Is there any chance that you had overwritten and/or changed /bin/tar permissions by accident before?